# FullName of generic base type

Tags: c#, generics, reflection

I have a hierarchy of classes which I'm trying to get Type names out of:

```
class Alice
    :ThirdPersonCharacter<Foo, Bar>

class ThirdPersonCharacter<A, B>
    :BaseHumanoidCharacter<A, B>, ISomeInterface
    where A : Something

class BaseHumanoidCharacter<A, B>
    : Entity,
    ISomeOtherInterface
    where A : Something
```

I want to get all the base types of Alice, so I'm doing this:

```
private static IEnumerable<Type> BaseTypes(Type t)
{
    while (t.BaseType != null)
    {
        yield return t.BaseType;
        t = t.BaseType;
    }
}

var aliceTypes = baseTypes(typeof(Alice)).Select(a => a.AssemblyQualifiedName).ToArray();
```

The problem is the type this is finding for BaseHumanoidCharacter is:

```
{Name = "BaseHumanoidCharacter`2" FullName = null}
```

of course what I really want is:

```
{Name = "BaseHumanoidCharacter`2[[X.Y.Z.Foo, AssemblyName, version=123, Culture=whatever, PublicKey=stuff],[X.Y.Z.Bar, AssemblyName, version=123, Culture=whatever, PublicKey=stuff]]", FullName = "Something that isn't null"}
```

Is there a way to modify this system to give me useful types with their generic parameters filled in, and their FullName not null?

Comment: In order to fully understand your class hierarchy it would be helpful if you also show the Character class that Alice is derived from - or is it a typo?

Comment: It was yes, sorry about that. I meant the more specific ThirdPersonCharacter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`FullName`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.fullname%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) returns something very like what you're looking for:

```
typeof(Tuple<int, string>).FullName
// System.Tuple`2[[System.Int32, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089],[System.String, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]]
```

There are some differences between this and your example, which may or may not matter depending on how you plan to use it

1. It includes the first type's namespace. You can fix this by taking a substring based on the length of the [`Namespace`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.namespace%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).
2. It includes not just the assembly name, but full assembly identifying string (Version, Culture, PublicKeyToken), making it pretty long.
3. The format's a bit different, there's an extra pair of `[]` brackets around the types.

If these last two are problematic, you should be able to build the string yourself using the various properties of [`Type`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Type%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) ([`GenericTypeArguments`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.generictypearguments%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), `Name`, `FullName`, etc.) and [`Assembly`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), combined with [`Split`ting](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) where needed (e.g. to separate the assembly name from other info).

Here's an example of selecting the `Name` and `FullName`:

```
var aliceTypes = BaseTypes(typeof(Alice)).Where(x => x == 
                           typeof(BaseHumanoidCharacter<Foo, Bar>))
                             .Select(a => new { a.Name, a.FullName }).ToArray();
Console.WriteLine(aliceTypes.Single());
```

Comment: Oops, the format differences are just a mistake on my part. I'll correct that in the question. The real problem is FullName is *not* returning a string like that (which is what I'd expect), for some reason in this case it's returning null. I expect it's something specific about the way the whole system is setup which why is why I gave an example of the entire class hierarchy.

Comment: More specifically, I suspect using BaseType is the wrong thing to do, but I'd not sure what alternative to use.

Comment: @Martin `BaseType` is fine. I can't reproduce your problem of it showing `null`. See the output of http://ideone.com/K60q3Z

Comment: Wow, that's a fantastic resource! I'll edit the example to see if I can reproduce the problem properly

Comment: Well, I sure feel like an idiot now. The system actually scans for certain types and does this base type name finding for them. I wasn't excluding all the base types/interfaces/abstract classes etc from the system. So I guess at some point it was looking at class ThirdPersonCharacter<A, B> and choking on that.

Comment: So I've accepted your answer, since it is indeed the correct way to do what I'm trying to do!